# How can I combine values from two columns?

Tags: text-processing

I have a file in the following format:

```
$ cat /tmp/raw
2015-01   5000   1000
2015-02   6000   2000
2015-03   7000   3000
```

Now, what I want is to get the combined value from columns 2 and 3 in each row so that results are as follows:

```
2015-01   6000
2015-02   8000
2015-03   9000
```

I tried this but it only shows last value in the file like 2015-03 value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try using `awk`:

```
awk '{ print $1, $2 + $3; }' /tmp/raw
```

Result will be (I suppose value for 2015-03 should be 10000):

```
2015-01 6000
2015-02 8000
2015-03 10000
```

Comment: I can't believe i got the reply this quick :O , I never get such quick reply on any other forum :) thank you the command worked perfectly :)

Comment: @SyedJahanzaib, If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mark the answer. and thank you all others too for there valuable time and replies, they helped me too in learning of achieving goals with different method :)

Comment: @SyedJahanzaib, although I earned nice badge for this answer I think more precise and comprehensive is terdon's answer.

Answer (score 16):

Here are a few ways:

1. Another awk approach

   ```
   awk '{$2+=$3;}NF--' file
   ```
2. Perl

   ```
   perl -lane 'print "$F[0] ",$F[1]+$F[2]' file
   ```

   or

   ```
   perl -ape 's/$F[1].*/$F[1]+$F[2]/e' file
   ```
3. Shell (much slower/less efficient than the above)

   ```
   while read a b c; do echo "$a $((b + c))"; done < file
   ```

Comment: `$2+=$3` may be more awky.

Comment: @User112638726 indeed it is. Thanks.

Comment: You could also use `awk '{$2+=$3}NF--'` so there isn't still a blank field 3 hanging about. Although thats just my preference, and its too similar to post as an answer on its own :)

Comment: @User112638726 now that one hadn't even occurred to me. Much neater, thanks!

Comment: I wrote [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/210140/52934) for you. Note how not only does `sed` somehow manage to understand *fields* - even to define *fields* on the fly, and *fields* w/in *fields* - but, as is apparently the case, the entire concept of Unix regexp matching is *actually based on dividing a string into **fields** according to a **pattern***! Who knew?

Answer (score 5):

```
sed 's/[^ ]* */[&]P/;s//&+pc/3'|dc
```

...prints...

```
2015-01   6000
2015-02   8000
2015-03   10000
```

So above I declare a *regular-expression* which defines a *field-extent* that consists of a *`*`variable-length* single sequence of characters which are *`^`not <space>* followed immediately by a *`*`variable-length* single sequence of characters which are *<space>*. This declaration is applied against `sed`'s pattern space, which is a string delimited *(by default)* by each `\n`ewline character which occurs in input, and which is recursively replaced *(by default)* with the next for each occurrence of same.

The interface for this declaration is two-fold, and at each level is fully regulated and specified by *at least one* [international IEEE official standards committee](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=POSIX) to ensure predictable application of `sed` command syntax. [`sed`'s API syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), for example, is applied in this case with the `/`address`/` command *(which is always the first component of any `sed s///`ubstitution command)*, but the contents of same is interpreted by a more basic API as a subset of that specified for the [*`regcomp()`*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regcomp.html) function in the [standard C library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_POSIX_library).

I can make these statements confidently, because `sed` is *not* merely a program, but, rather, the compiled executable named `sed` on my Unix-like machine is an *implementation* of the well-defined, historically established, and standards-controlled `sed` *application* of my system's regular-expression matching libraries.

---

From the `sed` spec:

> The `sed` utility shall support the BREs described in [XBD Basic Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03)...

...where we find...

> Both BREs and EREs are supported by the Regular Expression Matching interface in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2008 under [*`regcomp()`*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regcomp.html), [*`regexec()`*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regexec.html), and related functions.

An application which calls [*`regcomp()`*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regcomp.html) will present it a *pattern* string and...

> ...[t]he *`regcomp()`* function shall compile the regular expression contained in the string pointed to by the *pattern* argument and place the results in the structure *preg*...

To act on that, said application would then refer to *`regcomp()`*'s companion function...

> ...[t]he [*`regexec()`*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regexec.html) function compares the null-terminated string specified by *string* with the compiled regular expression *preg* initialized by a previous call to *`regcomp()`*...
>
> ...*`regexec()`* shall fill in the elements of [an] array with offsets of the substrings of *string* that correspond to the *`\(`* parenthesized subexpressions *`\)`* of *pattern*...*pattern* itself counts as a subexpression...
>
> ...[t]he *`regexec()`* function must fill in all *nmatch* elements of *pmatch*, where *nmatch* and *pmatch* are supplied by the application, even if some elements of *pmatch* do not correspond to subexpressions in *pattern*.

---

And so when I do...

```
/[^ ]* */
```

...`sed` first *compiles* the regular expression and stores the results in memory, then afterward applies the compiled-automaton stored there to the contents of my pattern-space as many times as is necessary to fulfill my command. Every time it does the result is an array of one-or-more null-delimited *fields* as delimited at the offsets returned by *`regexec()`*.

And when I do...

```
//
```

...to indicate that the most recently defined regular expression should be used, `sed` can just call *`regexec()`* again reusing the precompiled regular expression, but possibly applying it this time to a changed *string* argument or applying new *nmatch* parameters as I command.

More specifically still...

- `s/[^ ]* */[&]P/`

  - replace the first occurrence of *pattern* in pattern-space with a `[`left-square-bracket , then `&`itself, then a `]`right-square-bracket followed by a `P` character.
- `s//&+pc/3`

  - apply the last used regular expression again to the current pattern space, and replace the `3`third occurrence of *pattern* in pattern space with `&`itself followed by the appended string *`+pc`*.

And so for each line of `sed`'s input it writes to its stdout, given your example data:

```
[2015-01   ]P5000   1000+pc
[2015-02   ]P6000   2000+pc
[2015-03   ]P7000   3000+pc
```

---

This might look strange, but the `dc` calculator quotes *strings* in its input between square brackets, and the `P` command will both print the top of stack without appending a `\n`ewline and afterward pop that off of the input stack.

And so, using the first line there as an example, `dc` will do:

- `[2015-01   ]P`

  - `P`rint and pop the top of stack
- `5000`

  - Push the number `5000` onto the top of stack and push all elements currently on the stack *(now none)* down by one.
- `1000`

  - ditto, but this time the number 5000 at the top of the main stack is pushed down by one, and becomes the second element on the stack.
- `+`

  - Add the top two numbers on the stack together, pop both of those off of the stack and push the sum onto the top of stack.
  - This results in a stack consisting only of the number `6000`.
  - This is a syntax error if either of the top two elements on the stack is a `[`string`]`.
- `p`

  - `p`rint the top of stack followed by an appended `\n`ewline without popping it from off of the stack.
- `c`

  - `c`lear the stack

Comment: I believe it works, but I can't parse it. Overall, you're setting up an addition  for dc. The first pattern makes sense. I think it matches the date and trailing blanks, but I don't get what putting that inside the character class brackets ([&]) does. It would be great if you would spell this one out.

Comment: @Joe - any better?

Comment: Wow! That makes a lot more sense (and shows me a bunch of things I need to learn more about.)  In particular, I had never noticed the use of // to reuse the current pattern. That's the kind of thing you read over and forget until you run into an actual example. Thanks a lot. It made me laugh to see how much power could be packed into a miniscule command and how much it took to explain it.

Comment: @Joe - well... maybe i went a little overboard...